# "Link appears to be broken" when uploading large file

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, file-upload

When uploading a 42MB file through my ASP.NET Web Application, an issue is occuring where the following errors appear depending on the browser being used:

**Google Chrome:**

```
Oops! This link appears to be broken
```

**FireFox:**

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
```

**Internet Explorer**

```
The webpage cannot be found
```

I don't believe this is an issue with file size restrictions as I have the following in my web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="409600" executionTimeout="9000" />
```

This is working fine on our development server (IIS6), but not on the live server (IIS7)

Why is this and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What are the values of request max size and request timeout in your web.config ?

Comment: maxRequestLength is 409600, executionTimeout is 9000

Comment: Does the upload request reach your aspx page_load ? You can check by putting a BP on page load

Comment: @Ankur Can't test debugging as the issue is only on the live server, which we can't debug/BP :/

Comment: Hmm.. anything in IIS logs or Windows event logs from ASP.NET ?

Comment: Does this happen at the start of uploading or at the end? Can you test with Fiddler/Firebug etc and see what's coming back from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS7 doesn't seem to read:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="409600" />
```

The IIS7 alternative seems to be:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200"></requestLimits>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```